# R ggplot time series without grid arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a different time series for example 4. In this case, I simulated 4 white noise time series.

```
timeSeries <- matrix(nrow=500,ncol=4)

for(i in 1:4){
  timeSeries[,i] <- rnorm(n = 500,mean = 0,sd = i)
}
timeSeries <- as.data.frame(timeSeries)
timeSeries <- cbind(timeSeries,time = 1:500)
```

Each time series has a different standard deviation. I want to visualize all the time series using a line plot.

```
plot1 <- ggplot(timeSeries,aes(x = time,y= V1)) + geom_line()
plot2 <- ggplot(timeSeries,aes(x = time,y= V2)) + geom_line()
plot3 <- ggplot(timeSeries,aes(x = time,y= V3)) + geom_line()
plot4 <- ggplot(timeSeries,aes(x = time,y= V4)) + geom_line()

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, 
             plot3,plot4,
             nrow = 2, ncol=2)
```

This is the results at the moment: 
[image]

If I do how I'm doing now, the range is different between the plots. Can I use something like facet_wrap for doing this plot and have the same range of value between the plots?

Comment: Why don't you normalize the values beforehand?

Comment: the time series are different, I can't do it. I want to know if there is a difference between time series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention `facet_wrap`, perhaps something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
timeSeries %>%
    gather(key, val, -time) %>%
    ggplot(aes(time, val)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ key)
```

[image]

You can specify the behaviour the scales through the `scales` parameter in `facet_wrap`. The default are fixed (i.e. the same) scales for both axes across all facets.

Answer (score 2):

What about this approach?

```
ggplot(timeSeries %>% gather(key,value,-time)) +
geom_line(aes(x=time,y=value))+
facet_wrap(~key)
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question, you want the y-axis to have the same range for the four plots. The simple but maybe not the most efficient way is to add:

```
ylim(10,-10) #Add this to each plot like following example:
plot1 <- ggplot(timeSeries,aes(x = time,y= V1)) + geom_line() + ylim(10, -10)
```